# I'm trying to create a display which shows a number of components changing colors in a loop

Tags: java, loops, graphics, jframe, delay

My issue with the above is that graphic functions in java seems to only act at the end of a method, meaning that they will never produce an output during a loop, and that there's no way to delay the visual changes to keep them from happening all at once. If you try to delay the visual changes with sleep the code will just take longer to compile and then make all the visual changes at the very end all at once.

Here is a snipit of  the code I am working with:

```
public class simulation{     //this class is inside of my main class so it inherits all the objects 

public void update(){

//drawProgression is supposed to be called from here in a loop, and update is called from the main class
//I hanven't found a way to make this work though

}

//This method is meant to turn a grid of 12 panels green one by one
//pnM# are the panels
//This method works, but I can't find a way to loop it, or delay the actions so the user can see the changes as they happen
private void drawProgression(){

       if(progressionCounter>11){
           progressionCounter=0;
       }

       if(progressionCounter==0){
       pnM1.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM12.setBackground(GRAY);
       }
       if(progressionCounter==1){
       pnM2.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM1.setBackground(GRAY);
       }
       if(progressionCounter==2){
       pnM3.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM2.setBackground(GRAY);
       }   
       if(progressionCounter==3){
       pnM4.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM3.setBackground(GRAY);
       }
       if(progressionCounter==4){
       pnM5.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM4.setBackground(GRAY);
       }
       if(progressionCounter==5){
       pnM6.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM5.setBackground(GRAY);
       }
       if(progressionCounter==6){
       pnM7.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM6.setBackground(GRAY);
       }
       if(progressionCounter==7){
       pnM8.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM7.setBackground(GRAY);
       }
       if(progressionCounter==8){
       pnM9.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM8.setBackground(GRAY);
       }
       if(progressionCounter==9){
       pnM10.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM9.setBackground(GRAY);
       }
       if(progressionCounter==10){
       pnM11.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM10.setBackground(GRAY);
       }
       if(progressionCounter==11){
       pnM12.setBackground(GREEN);
       pnM11.setBackground(GRAY);
       }

       progressionCounter++;
   }
   }
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible in Java, or Java JFrame From? How would I go about it because I've been stumped for hours. Thanks.

Comment: You can you javax.swing.Timer to solve this

Comment: MVC could be useful, your progressionCounter will be your Model and then whenver the progressionCounter gets incremented, you automatically call update() which runs your function then repaints the pnM#'s